# Как принять JSON ответ на PHP?

Tags: php, json

На фронте при нажатии на кнопку собираю все данные с форми в JSON и отправляю на сервер

```
const onSubmit = async values => {
console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
return fetch('http://shop-api.local/API/feedbackForm.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(values),
}).then(res => {
    return res;
}).catch(err => err);
};
```

JSON

```
{"name":"Dan","email":"dan@mail.com","message":"bla bla bla"}
```

Нужно принять этот json на сервере и запись в бд, как то так пробовал, не работает

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));


$sql = "INSERT INTO Feedback (name, email, message) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$message')";
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die("Ошибка " .     mysqli_error($link));

if ($result)
echo "Добавлено в базу данных.";

mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Посмотрите сперва, что приходит в $_POST: `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($json, true);
    print_r($obj);
```

Получится простой ассоциативный массив, вот такой:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Dan
    [email] => dan@mail.com
    [message] => bla bla bla
)
```

дальше читаете $obj и распихиваете по переменным.

```
$name = $obj['name'];
$email = $obj['email'];
$message = $obj['message'];
```

$_POST здесь вам не поможет, так как в нем нет этих данных.

Comment: Ура! все заработало! Огромное спасибо за помощь!